# How to zoom into an image towards a specific point + keeping track of specific points after zooming

Tags: python, image, matlab, zooming

I would like to zoom into an image towards a specific defined point in the image.

Also, there is a bounding box in the image of which I know the coordinates of its 4 corners. I would like to keep track of these points while I am zooming into the image and after having zoomed image I would have the coordinates of 4 corners of bounding box in the zoomed image, if the bounding box is still in the zoomed image.

Comment: I do not understand where the problem is exactly? What keeps you from doing exactly what you want to do?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using matplotlib for this approach just as an example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

import numpy as np

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

#create 2d array
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
x, y = np.meshgrid(t, t)
img = np.sin(x-0.5)*np.sin(y-0.5)

ax.imshow(img, origin='lower', extent=[0, 1, 0, 1])
#create a rectangle at positions 0.1, 0.1 with width/height 0.5
#so this would be your bounding box from points (0.1, 0.1), (0.6,0.6) etc
rectangle = patches.Rectangle((0.1, 0.1), 0.5, 0.5, fill=False)
ax.add_patch(rectangle)

plt.show()

print ax.get_xlim()
print ax.get_ylim()
```

This creates the following output after plot show

[image]

So after this plot opens in matplotlib you can zoom into the plot using the right mouse button. If you close the plot the programm flow continues with `print ax.get_xlim()` etc.. 
This will give you the new limits of your plot from which you should be able to compute your new point positions

I don't know how famillar you are with python / matplotlib but this should be pretty straight forward, otherwise let me know if you need more explanations

Comment: right click of the mouse doesn't work. and the image is not zoomed.

Comment: have a look at http://www.ster.kuleuven.be/~pieterd/python/html/plotting/interactive.html